# Should a header be included in a file if that header is already implicitly included?

Tags: c, gcc, header, include

I am wondering: **should a header be included in a file if that header is already implicitly included?** For example

`dataStructure.h`

```
#ifndef DATASTRUCTURE_H
#define DATASTRUCTURE_H

typedef struct MyStruct_ {
    int number;
    ... // other members
} MyStruct;

#endif
```

`utils.h`

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

#include "dataStructure.h"
int GetSize(MyStruct* my_struct);
int PrimeNumber(int my_struct_number);

#endif
```

`main.c`

```
 #include "utils.h" 
 // utils.h includes `dataStructure.h` but should I include it again here?

 int main() {
     MyStruct my_struct;
     ... // initialise my_struct

     if (PrimeNumber(my_struct.number)) {
         printf("%d is prime\n", my_struct.number);
     }
 }
```

If later `GetSize` method is deleted in `utils.h` file, `utils.h` no longer needs to include `dataStructure.h`. Then after these modifications suddenly `main.c` can not compile without the `dataStructure.h` header.

A real-life example would be whether or not to include `<stdlib.h>` for using a `NULL` pointer if most likely this will be implicitly included in some other header file and the code compiles without the extra inclusion.

Are these examples demonstrate a reason to re-include a file if it is already implicitly included?

Comment: My opinion is that you should include what you use where you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the header file as many times as you want if some conditions are met:

1. The `.h` file is guarded by the definitions (your code is missing guards). It assures that the body of the .h file will be compiled only one time in every compilation unit.

```
#ifndef DATASTRUCTURE_h
#define DATASTRUCTURE_h

/* the content of the .h file */

#endif
```

2. Your code does not contain any data or function definitions except static inline functions. It can contain `extern` object declarations and function prototypes and data types declarations.

Is it good or not? Personally I prefer to see what particular compilation unit will use accepting the penalty related to the multple preprocessing.